# bent upon exerting the fascination he knew was his only by the results

Tags: meaning, grammar

I read this in the novel 'Of Human Bondage' by Somerset Maugham.

It follows as below.
'Philip was even more than usually shy and abrupt; and whether on account of this, **unconsciously bent upon exerting the fascination he knew was his only by the results**, or whether from sheer kindness of heart, It was Rose who first took Philip into the circle.'

Is it all right if I suppose like this?
(For Rose being) unconsciously bent upon exerting the fascination he knew was his (fascination) only by the results

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to look up the original passage to figure out the answer --it helps to know that Rose is a boy, and that the excerpt you quoted is does not contain the beginning of the sentence, which states in full:

*With Rose, because he was as little able as anyone else to resist his charm, Philip was even more than usually shy and abrupt; and whether on account of this, unconsciously bent upon exerting the fascination he knew was his only by the results, or whether from sheer kindness of heart, it was Rose who first took Philip into the circle.*

So, this passage tells us that (1) Philip is fascinated by Rose's charm --it makes him act shy.  (2) Rose notices the effect he has on Philip, which is his only way of knowing Philip is fascinated by him. (3) Rose takes Philip into the circle of boys --either because of kindness or because he subconsciously enjoys the impact he has on Philip.

In other words, your supposition is basically correct.